# Is getServletContext() officially supported in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

Is `getServletContext()` officially supported in GAE?

- is it ok if servers are distributed among diff locations?
- performance?
- could I use 'synchronize' within the doPost or in a task queue before updating a value in the context?

Comment: @bach, i've noticed you've asked a bunch of questions all related to the idea of global synchronization of one kind or another.  Maybe if you post exactly what  you are trying to do, we can help you find a solution that does not involve reducing your application to a single thread on a single box :)

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the basic servlet spec, so yes, it's supported. However, as [the docs](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) say:

> In the case of a web application
>   marked "distributed" in its deployment
>   descriptor, there will be one context
>   instance for each virtual machine. In
>   this situation, the context cannot be
>   used as a location to share global
>   information (because the information
>   won't be truly global). Use an
>   external resource like a database
>   instead.

Comment: No - App Engine is fundamentally a distributed infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServletContext but there will be one context per instance of your app. So you can't rely on the ServletContext to share information globally. You do have alternatives though (and good ones at that) - use either memcache or the datastore.